# C# - Compiler error

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I am making an app in C# using Mono and I am referencing two libraries which is giving me an error. How can I mae it so that i only reference one.

this is the error i am getting

`Error  1   The type 'System.Drawing.RectangleF' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoTouch\v4.0\monotouch.dll'  C:\Users\cmtc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\BoostITAndroid\BoostITAndroid\HelperClasses\RightAlignedEntryElement.cs 19  50  BoostITAndroid`

how do I make it so I only select System.Drawing.RectangleF from one of the libraries

Comment: Remove the reference to the one you don't want? Or am I not fully understanding your question

Comment: @tnw I cant remove the reference from my project because I need both, but do you know a way to remove it just from that class in the code?

Comment: @tnw do you know a way to dynamically remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Alias referencing:

```
using Name1 = Android.Mono;
using Name2 = Monotouch;
```

Wherever you are using the reference, use the alias name that you wanted to use, for example;

```
Name1.RectangleF rectF = new Name1.RectangleF();
```

This way you keep both reference.

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved was to remove an unwanted reference in the android project: Xamarin.iOS or check if you have Android.Mono on your iOS project. If you do have such reference, remove it, close visual studio and rebuild