# Xamarin.forms error when use RectangleF

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I user Xamarin.forms . please fix for me that error. thank you so much !

```
 RectangleF imageRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0433  The type 'RectangleF' exists in both 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' and 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' MedlatecService C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MedlatecService\MedlatecService\MedlatecService\Views\AskQuestion\AskQuestionPage.xaml.cs  128 Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are using a shared project or a PCL project but, the first link in Google results:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552126/3850012

Basically you need to use an alias to tell the compiler which version of the `RectangleF` you want to use.

In your using statements:

```
using Name1 = Android.Mono;
using Name2 = Monotouch;
```

Then:

```
Name1.RectangleF imageRect = new Name1.RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);
```

Comment: hey ! thanks you so much. 
I have been try it before but not done . 

I use PLC  project not Shareproject . So I try mix that to Dependenc and fix that. 
thank you again !

Comment: @TháiHòa Happy to help. Please mark as an answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Where you added this statements? i have conflict with System.Drawing.Rectangle, and Color. I tried to add this namespaces as Name1 and Name2 but i have redmarked Android."Mono" and "Monotouch".

Answer (score 2):

Funny, I had the same problem.

I don't know how it happened, but somehow I added a reference to Mono.Android in my iOS project; hence the error.

I removed the reference and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add aliases (i could not in netstandard project) in code just go to:

```
Solution name
\_
   Depedencies
  \_
     Assemblies
   \_
      Mono.Android
```

[image: Path to mono android]

Click on **Mono.Android** and choose **Settings**, then you will see **General** menu. Expand that and edit row named **Aliases**. You can write here anything, but remember that it will be Your Alias to use Mono.Android namespace.

[image]